# Tricky method for overriding a method in several sibling classes required

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Imagine a situation in which a large set of animal classes, **which cannot be modified**, all inherit from the same parent class "Animal", and each implements a method called "make_noise" each with a slightly different signature, but all with shared parameter volume:

```
class Cat(Animal)
    def make_noise(volume, duration)
        -some code here-

class Mouse(Animal)
    def make_noise(volume, pitch)
        -some different code here-
```

A different "controller" class, **which also cannot be modified**, is instructing a list of these animal instances (a list which I have populated) to make sounds at particular volumes (and duration/pitch/etc as appropriate). However, I need to get between the controller and animal classes to modify the behaviour of "make_noise" in all animal classes, so that I can reduce the value of volume before the sound is made.

One option would be to do something like:

```
def animal_monkeypatcher(animal_class, volume_reduction_factor):
    class QuietAnimal(animal_class)
        def make_noise(volume, **kwargs)
            volume = volume * volume_reduction_factor
            super(QuietAnimal, self).make_noise(volume, **kwargs)
```

However, I also need to pickle these objects, and that doesn't work with this approach. The next approach I thought about was a class which had an instance of the animal like so...

```
class QuietAnimal():
    def __init__(animal_class, init_kwargs):
        self.animal = animal_class(**init_kwargs)

    def make_noise(volume, **kwargs)
        volume = volume * volume_reduction_factor
        self.animal.make_noise(volume, **kwargs)

    def lots of other functions.....
```

However, this is also not suitable because the controller sometimes needs to create new instances of animals. It does this by getting the class of an animal (which is QuietAnimal, instead of say Mouse) and then using the same set of init_kwargs to create it, which does not match the signature of QuietAnimal, so again we're stuck...

At the moment I have a horrible hack, which basically forks the init depending on whether or not an animal_class has been passed in or not, and records some info in some class variables. It's frankly dreadful, and not useful if I need to create more than one type of animal (which in my use case I don't, but still...). It's also rubbish because I have to include all of the methods from all of the animals.

What is the appropriate way to wrap/proxy/whatever this set of classes to achieve the above? Some sample code would be greatly appreciated. I am a Python novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, what I needed was standard ["monkey patching"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monkey-patching-in-python-dynamic-behavior/). Not a great idea either, but slightly cleaner than creating classes on the fly.